# Python 2.7: What print() does to the string inside of it

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been using the `print()` syntax in my python 2.7 files even though I know that in 2.7 `print` is a statement, and not a function like in 3.X.  But the python interpreter didn't seem to have any problem with the `print()` syntax, so I kept it to make a possible future port to 3.X easier.  But I noticed something fishy about the way Python was treating the string literal inside the parenthesis:

```
>>>> print("\nFirst line\n", "Second line")

('\First line\n', 'Second line')
```

Whereas the typical 2.7 statement syntax prints the newline characters as expected:

```
>>>>print "\nFirst line\n", "Second line"

First line
Second line
```

### Question:

So whats the reasoning behind the print()  working in 2.7 but ignoring the `\n` character?  It is almost like print() is printing out the `__repr__` string of the contained string literal.

Comment: Could not replicate in Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Although the Python 2.7.x interpreter doesn't have problems with the syntax, it surely doesn't look pretty. Try `print('a', 'b', 'c')`  in Python 3: `a b c` and in Python 2.x: `('a', 'b', 'c')`

Comment: That's not what it does in 2.7.7 for me.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for pointing that out, I paraphrased my code to make it easier to understand out of context and didn't realize that it was the comma that turned it into a tuple.  Next time I'll rerun my code before uploading

Comment: @joshsvoss: Use `from __future__ import print_function` to get the same syntax for the `print` in Python 2 as in Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround any expression with parentheses without changing its value, so:

```
print ("hello world")
```

is *exactly* the same as:

```
print "hello world"
```

It *looks* like a function call at first blush, but in fact you are simply printing a string expression that happens to be in parentheses. Same deal as this:

```
x = 1 + 2   # same as
x = (1 + 2)
```

However, if you try to print multiple items, or print with a comma at the end of your string (which is often used ot avoid printing the newline), you will get the kind of results you're describing:

```
print ("hello", "world")
print ("hello world",)
```

In this case you are printing a tuple.

```
t = ("hello", "world")   # or
t = ("hello world", )

print t
```

And printing a tuple does in fact print the `repr()` of each item within it.

Comment: Yes. Which is why I said it doesn't actually do what he said it does.